# Как двигать/копировать объекты слитно?

Tags: html, css, html5, css-animation, css-selectors

Как заставить объекты двигаться вместе? [image: введите сюда описание изображения] вот как тут, у меня тут все отдельно, отдельно, текст, отдельно кнопка, и тд, а как это соеденить? Не могу найти

Comment: Добавьте больше информации, сейчас мало что понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй объединить все в один блок и его двигать, иначе не получится. Что то типа этого:

```
<div class="knopka">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <p>Origin</p>
    <p>Акаунт</p>
    <button>Купить за 150</button>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.knopka{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
width: 30%;
height: 60%;
background: #7974f4;
}
```

а там уже красоту наведешь